# Word for someone who speaks on behalf of a deity

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for someone who speaks on behalf of a deity? *Not* that the *deity* speaks through them or channels through them<sup>1</sup>, but that *they* speak **on behalf** of the deity. Like when an angel speaks on behalf of God. Here, an angel conveys God's message *for* Him. God Himself does not convey the message.

I've thought of ***mouthpiece***:

> a person or organization who speaks on behalf of another person or organization.
> *the media acts as a mouthpiece for the Party*
>
> ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mouthpiece))

But I would like to know if there are other more suitable words.

---

<sup>1</sup> Clarification: When *God* speaks *through* a being (for example, a donkey), He is projecting His voice through the being to convey His message; that is, God Himself is delivering the message, *not* appointing someone to deliver the message *for* Him. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you specifically referring to an angel or supernatural being? There are certain terms such as prophet that really only apply to humans.

Comment: I know that in reality both ***pontiff*** and ***pontificate*** derive from a Latin word for ***to be pope*** - but speaking as a committed atheist, I just wish they'd both derived from some ancestor word with *today's* most common meaning for the latter! :)

Comment: *Messenger* can apply to both humans and angels.

Comment: No, _pontiff_ ultimately means 'bridge-maker', the name for the head of the Roman priesthoods, _pontifex maximus_. A pontifex made bridges between men and gods. And often spoke on their behalf, though practices varied. Most gods didn't talk to men much, and when they did  the other gods would often interrupt and argue, or rather their priests would. Gods are a surly lot; comes of having your own way too often.

Comment: Technically, a priest spoke (interceded) to gods on behalf of men, while a prophet typically spoke to men on behalf of gods. So priest and pontiff are not quite right.

Comment: Can you Post three or four examples, please? "… Not that the deity speaks… or channels through them, but that they speak on behalf of them. Like when an angel speaks on behalf of God…" does not seem usefully clear to me, for one.

Comment: Which deity? There's three correct answers below, depending on what religion.

Comment: Needs example sentence or usage. If you're looking for (tactless) wordplay, try [burning bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_bush).

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: If I'm correct, when a deity speaks *through* someone, it means that the **deity** is doing the talking using someone else as a *medium*. *On behalf of* means that the deity does *not* do the talking, but uses someone else to do the talking *for* them. For example, a deity speaking through a donkey (the *deity* is projecting their voice through the donkey), compared to a person relaying a message from the deity (the deity is *not* speaking, but someone else is *for* them.). I've added a slight clarification to the question, if that helps.

Comment: @Mazura there are approximately 10000 distinct religions on Earth. I suppose there are more than 3 possible answers.

Answer (score 72):

When applied to *humans*, a more suitable term would be ***prophet***:

> In religion, a prophet is an individual who is regarded as being in contact with a divine being and **is said to speak on behalf of that being**, serving as an intermediary with humanity by delivering messages or teachings from the supernatural source to other people.
>
> (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophet))

The word [*angel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel) comes from the Latin *angelus*, borrowed from the Greek *angelos*, which literally means *messenger*. Hence, a more general term, which can be applied to *both* humans and angels, would be ***messenger***.

From the OED (second edition) entry for [***messenger***](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00144991):

> **a**. One who carries a message or goes on an [errand](https://www.lexico.com/definition/errand); [...]
>
> **(God's) messenger**: (a) **used for *angel*** *n*., as representing the etymological sense of that word, and as expressing the function assigned to angels in Scripture; (b) **applied to a prophet**, or to a clergyman, as charged with a message from God to mankind.
>
> - **1558**  Knox *First Blast* (Arb.) 6   *The especiall dutie of Goddes messagers is to preache repentance*.
>
> **b**. The bearer of (a specified message).
>
> - **1583**  Golding *Calvin on Deut.* cix. 672   *Yet doth God appoint vs to be‥ messagers of his vnfallible trueth.*

So a *prophet* is a human messenger and an *angel* is a spiritual messenger, both of whom are sent to convey a message / speak on behalf of a deity.

Comment: _Angel_ has an interesting origin indeed. Its Latin etymon _angelus_ assumed quite a few meanings throughout the history. Here are them (from earliest to latest) per _OED_: evil spirit, demon, good spirit, messenger, ministering spirit, spiritual being, messenger of God, preacher, prophet, gold coin (from 1509 in British sources). Many of these senses are from Vulgate, the principal Latin version of the Bible. Good answer.

Answer (score 38):

An alternative to the rightly suggested *prophet* is ***oracle***.
Definition by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/oracle):

> A priest or priestess acting as a medium through whom advice or prophecy was sought from the gods in classical antiquity.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oracle) offers a more open definition:

> The agency or medium giving [the response of a god to an inquiry].

Comment: "The word [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle) comes from the Latin verb *ōrāre*, "to speak" and properly refers to the **priest** or **priestess** uttering the prediction. " - **medium** "a means by which something is communicated or expressed."

Comment: Oracle has a very strong predictive connotation. I really only hear the word oracle and think of ancient Greek myths, like the Oracle of Delphi, who foretold the future in a number of different myths (Minotaur's labyrinth & Oedipus to name two)

Answer (score 32):

I believe you're looking for the word ***herald***.

[Merriam-Webster's usage example matches your case exactly:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/herald)

> : an official crier or messenger
> *Mercury was the gods' herald*.

The word isn't restricted to deities and doesn't invoke speaking for a deity implicitly, but it's commonly understood in the sense you're looking for when a deity is mentioned explicitly.

Comment: *"Hark! The herald angels sing"*

Comment: “Hark the [Herald Tribune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Herald_Tribune) sins / [Advertising wondrous things](https://youtu.be/DtZR3lJobjw)”

Comment: Herald has the further advantage of specifying that they are collaborating with the deity in question, but are independently creating a statement to speak on behalf. Prophet connotes that they are sharing the unedited message of the deity rather than drafting their own.

Answer (score 14):

Another word that comes to mind is ***emissary***.

While [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emissary) mainly highlights the usage for someone who is "send out" in a political context, I also remember cases where it's used in a religious context (e.g. in [Star Trek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Emissary_of_the_Prophets)).

The concept of a ***divine emissary*** seems to be common enough that it has its own [entry on tvtropes.org](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EmissaryFromTheDivine).

Answer (score 12):

In Hinduism, there's the concept of an [avatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar). Someone who is the earthly incarnation of a god. They can be considered to be the actor on behalf of that god:

> Avatar (Sanskrit: अवतार, avatāra; pronounced [ɐʋɐtaːrɐ]), is a concept
> within Hinduism that in Sanskrit literally means "descent". It signifies
> the material appearance or incarnation of a deity on Earth.

In Buddhism, there's the concept of a [bodhisattva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhisattva). Buddha himself is considred to be one:

> In Buddhism, a bodhisattva (/ˌboʊdiːˈsʌtvə/ BOH-dee-SUT-və;
> Sanskrit:  (Brahmī), romanized: bodhisattva)[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhisattva) or bodhisatva
> is any person who is on the path towards bodhi ('awakening') or Buddhahood.

In Catholicism, the pope is considered the earthly embodiment of God's authority, particularly when they make a pronouncement ["ex-cathedra"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_infallibility):

> Papal infallibility is a dogma of the Catholic Church which states
> that, in virtue of the promise of Jesus to Peter, the pope when he
> speaks ex cathedra is preserved from the possibility of error on doctrine
> "initially given to the apostolic Church and handed down in Scripture
> and tradition".

Comment: +1 since *avatar* and *bodhisattva* are certainly relevant and good to have in the range or comparison, but I think these are not what OP is looking for.  Both of these are the deity inhabiting a mortal being and speaking through it; the question explicitly clarifies that OP wants not this, but a mortal speaking on behalf of the deity.

Comment: @PLL - I'll concede the point on avatar but I'm far from certain that a bodhisattva would be considered to be a god by most Buddhists. I think they would tend to see them more as an especially knowledgeable prophet. One granted particular insight but speaking their own words in teaching that insight. Do you have any references for your position?

Comment: Right, my earlier comment was sloppily written, and the second half only really applies to avatars.  I agree, as I understand it, a bodhisattva or Buddha isn’t usually considered a deity (though this is a subtle point, and as much about translation between traditions as anything else).  But what I had in mind was that as far as I know, there’s no sense in which a Buddha or bodhisattva is speaking *on behalf of* someone/something else.  Insofar as there’s any analogue of a deity in the picture at all, it’s the Buddha/boddhisattva themself.

Comment: That's an interesting point of view. I do know that some Buddhists do revere bodhisattvas as something close to (if not) a deity but my thought was that their teachings were pointing to some external reality outside of themselves. Something that would exist even if they themselves did not: a way of living that minimizes suffering for all and an external reality to ascend to. Maybe I'm taking a too christian-centric a view of a god being central to reality. Thanks for a good discussion!

Answer (score 5):

Some words used less often, with quotes from [the Wikipedia entry for Metatron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatron) (emphasis added)

> Metatron appears in the movie *Dogma* as an angel and the **voice** of God ....

> Metatron appears as an angel and the **spokesperson** of God in the book *Good Omens* ....

In the New International Version translation of Jeremiah 15:19, we have:

> Therefore this is what the LORD says:
>
> “[...]
> if you utter worthy, not worthless, words,
>
> you will be my **spokesman**.

Other translations say either “spokesman” or “as my mouth.”

Until the late twentieth-century, a woman could also be a “spokesman,” but the exclusively-female forms **prophetess** and **spokeswoman** also exist.  They are rarely used today.  The Greek word **Angela**, meaning a female messenger, is used only as a given name in English.

Another possibility is **mouthpiece**.  In some religious traditions, you might use loanwords such as, for example, *navi* from Hebrew.

Comment: Interestingly, biblical use of the word *navi* to mean "prophet" specifically refers to the aspect of speaking God's word to people (as opposed to other terms that roughly translate to "seer" or similar). It's even used to refer to a "spokesperson" rather than a prophet in Exodus 7:1

Comment: @Esther this is getting a bit off-topic (but very interesting!) Exodus 4:16 provides some context for the unusual usage you cite (the only use of the form *neviecha*, “your (m. sg.) prophet,” in the Hebrew Bible).

Comment: [Metatron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatron) makes his first appearance in the talmud

Answer (score -2):

Just in case this person merely *pretends* to speak on behalf of a deity, e.g. to gain some power, control or money, you could use :

- a *liar*
- a [*con artist*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/con-artist)
- a [*charlatan*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/charlatan)
- an [*impostor*/*imposter*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impostor)
- a *deceiver*
- a *cheat*

Comment: Downvoter: constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: this is clearly not the point, no need to throw your own opinions/beliefs into this. Not the downvoter, but somewhat annoyed.

Comment: of course there are many such impostors. I assume that the implication that "speaking on behalf of deity" necessarily = "con artist/ etc" is what annoyed someone.

Comment: If the OP wanted a word for "pretend prophet" they would have said that, no?

Comment: @Esther: answers are supposed to be informative for the whole community, not just for OP. I'll delete my comments.